# Enterprise Data Warehouse - Should the EDW table be named the same as it is in the source system

Tags: data-warehouse, enterprise

So we are loading an EDW with several Electronic Medical Record systems. We give each source system a database, internally referred to as a source mart. Then we merge similar data into tables into another database called Essentials.

I am curious as to the best practice for naming the tables at the source mart. I think they should maintain the exact same name as the source system. That way when apps are ported over we have some level of lineage to map to. Developers on the existing system would know that the table PAT_REF is patient data on both systems and would not have to maintain a second dictionary to figure out that table has been named something else.

But once we merge tables from multiple systems into the Essentials database we would rename the tables based on what Data governance worked out wit hall parties involved in using the data.

I could swear I saw this in one of the bazillion best practices documents out there, but I only seem to find docs going through normalization steps at the first level of data. I don't see trying to design fact and dimensions at that level and then trying to merge them with the other source systems. not to mention the huge hit those normalized queries we put on the source server.

Answer (score 1):

We use the same table name in our staging area as we do in our source systems.
To load them into the combined data warehouse we write views that define relationships and dependencies from the source systems. Then in the data warehouse the table names reflect that of the views used to load them.